# Self attention and multi input model in tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, attention-model

I am trying to use Tensorflow Functional API (https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/functional) to define a multi input neural network and add self attention layer after my embedding layer (https://pypi.org/project/keras-self-attention/). This is my code:

```
from keras_self_attention import SeqSelfAttention
from tensorflow import keras
Input1 = Input(shape=(120, ),name="Input1")
Input2 = Input(shape=(10, ),name="Input2")
embedding_layer = Embedding(30,5,  input_length=120,)(Input1) 
lstm_layer = tf.keras.layers.Bidirectional(tf.keras.layers.LSTM(units=512))(embedding_layer)                  
attention=SeqSelfAttention(attention_activation='sigmoid')(lstm_layer) 
merge = concatenate([attention, Input2])
```

However, I get this error:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, None, 1024), (None, 10)].
```

I only have one sequence in input and I want to apply self attention to it and then concatenate with another input. How can I do that?

Comment: Is `keras_self_attention` is written with `tf 2.x`? If not, I think we can't mix-up both versions.

Comment: It is ok based on https://github.com/CyberZHG/keras-self-attention/issues/18. Any clue why I am getting this error?

Comment: Is the given code that you've tried so far? It seems not multi-input! And why passing embedding layer to flatten instead of passing to sequence layer, i.e LSTM?

Comment: My bad. You are right. I do not need flatten layer. Why do you add sequence layer such as dense layer or LSTM layer between embedding layer and self attention layer? Why do not you add self attention layer right after embedding layer?

Comment: Truly we don't have to set a sequence layer, I was just assuming. And yes you can add the self-attention layer right after the embedding layer. I ran the code successfully according to your given code snippet. But I'm pretty sure that not you wanted.

Comment: @hsn15051 `SeqSelfAttention` doesn't accepted 2D input, remove flattening. I recommend you to add it after the self attention, as you're passing the output to a dense layer.

Comment: @Ghanem Now, my problem is that SeqSelfAttention creates (None, None, 1024) shape output and I can not concatenate it with second set of inputs which has shape (None, 10). Do you have any idea how to solve it?

Comment: @hsn15051 your question is not clear at all. I can't see anything in your code about concatenation! It's all about what do you want to do.

Comment: @Ghanem I tried my sample code to be very simple but it has become more confusing. Sorry for that. I have updated my question with exact code. Could you please let me know what you think? Thanks

Comment: @hsn15051 , of course it won't work. you have a 3d tensor and a 2d one. Is this attention layer that you want? are you sure self-attention?

Comment: @hsn15051 Ok then this is not the attention layer that you need. Search for attention with average vector instead of this attention layer.